# Why am I seeing Selenium web driver in my error message though I am using Watir webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir space.
I am tring to develop an automation script using Watir webdriver and cucumber.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec-expectations'
require 'cucumber'
```

@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => 'default')

When some error happens I can see that the error message has Selenium webdriver mentioned in it. (I dont have the error message now. will add it once I see it again)

Why is it when I am using Watir I am seeing selinium webdriver errors?

Note: I have installed selenium-webdriver in my machine but not requiring in the current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver) page,

```
Runtime Dependencies
selenium-webdriver >= 2.18.0
```

It seems that `Watir` is built ontop of `Selenium`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Now I understand things better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes... Watir webdriver is a wrapper on top of Selenium webdriver.  When you install watir webdriver, selenium also will get installed as a dependency....